# MFC: Window responds too slowly

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have the following code in my Frame Window Class

```
void CMainFrame::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
}
```

And I have a button up event handler

```
void CMainFrame::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
    CShapes shape;
    CFrameWnd::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect client;
    GetClientRect(&client);
    shape.DrawRectangle(&dc, client, 10,10, 10,10);
    shape.DrawRoundRectangle(&dc, client, 50, 50, 50, 50, 20, 20);
}
```

But the rectangle is not painted after button. However, when I remove the `CPaintDC dc(this);` from the void `CMainFrame::OnPaint()` it works but then the window responds very slowly. It is consuming too much memory.

Also tried using `AfxGetMainWnd()` instead of `this` in `CPaintDC dc()` in `void CMainFrame::OnPaint()` but it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it gets so slow is that you are creating an infinite "do-nothing" loop. Two absolute rules you must follow:

The OnPaint handler **must** have CPaintDC(this);

All other message handlers **must not** contain CPaintDC.

Move your painting into OnPaint.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do your paint code in the button handler.  Move the code from your `OnLButtonUp` to your `OnPaint` routine, after the `CPaintDC dc(this)` call (but take out the `CFrameWnd::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);` code).

`CPaintDC dc(this)` should ONLY be called in the `OnPaint` routine, not in the button handler.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a48eab8d.aspx - *A CPaintDC object can only be used when responding to a WM_PAINT message, usually in your OnPaint message-handler member function.*)

Calling `Invalidate` in the paint routine will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

`CPaintDC` is a RAII object where it wraps `BeingPaint()` in the `ctor` and `EndPaint()` in the `dtor` (happens at the end of the function). So in this case, you're not drawing drawing anything. `OnPaint` is called whenever a window needs painting. It's not even driven by user. It happens on quite a few events like window activation, overlapping etc. And a button click wouldn't fire an `OnPaint` event unless it causes a repaint to the window or forcefully `Invalidate`. Also CPaintDC only used within OnPaint function. For other drawing you will have use CDC class. (call `GetDC()` do the paint operation and `ReleaseDC()`)

I suggest to write the drawing code within `OnPaint` function for persistent drawing. The data for drawing the  rectangle can be stored within the class and indicate using flags (flag based coding isn't a good idea though) and draw inside the `OnPaint` function. The problem with drawing in the event handler (button click) is the drawing would disappear when the window get refreshed. How about something like this?

```
void CMainFrame::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    if(draw_rect)
    {
        CShapes shape;
        CRect client;
        GetClientRect(&client);
        shape.DrawRectangle(&dc, client, 10,10, 10,10);
        shape.DrawRoundRectangle(&dc, client, 50, 50, 50, 50, 20, 20);
    }
}

void CMainFrame::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
    CFrameWnd::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
        draw_rect = true;
}
```

Comment: It isn't working.. Here's my code.
void CMainFrame::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
 CFrameWnd::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
 draw_rect = true;
 SendMessage(WM_PAINT);
}
void CMainFrame::OnPaint() 
{
 CPaintDC dc(this);
 CRect client;
 GetClientRect(&client);
 if(draw_rect==true) {
  shape.DrawRectangle(&dc, client, 10,10, 10,10);
 }
}

Answer (score -2):

It worked..
I added `Invalidate();` at the end of the `CMainFrame::OnPaint()` method and it worked.

```
void CMainFrame::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I don't think invalidating inside a paint function a good idea.

Comment: Trust me, this is a bad idea.

Comment: Calling `InvalidateRect` in between `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` doesn't make sense. Stop clicking code together and read [a book](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-MFC-Second-Edition/dp/1572316950).

Comment: I am unable to pull it out what I want to achieve. I need to generate a new rectangle(shape) every time I click. And I can't even get to show one.